# Angular 2 / Typescript: For loop with HTTP request issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-http

I have a HTTP get request that use a book name in url to find a price for the book.
I added a loop to get all the prices of the books added to to array. But it seems like the next iterations don't go through. Books[0] works fine and price are added from the API.

When I try to log the iterations, it also stops after index 0.

```
books: {  name: String, price: String} [] = [
    { "name": "dash", "price": "N/A" }
    { "name": "tash", "price": "N/A" }
    { "name": "mash", "price": "N/A" }
];

getti() {
    var i: number;
    for (i = 0; i < this.books.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        return this.http.get(url+this.books[i].name)
            .map(res => {
                if (res)
                    this.books[i].price = res.json();
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not be doing one http request per iteration. you should rather send your array to server, have server filter collection that meets criteria (array) and return all. that way you have just one http call and no loop.

Comment: You can only return once from a function, after that it's over and the rest of your loop never happens. Look into the RxJS methods e.g. concatAll to combine the results of multiple requests and return a single observable.

Comment: deezg, Okay, I don't have acces to server side.

@jonrsharpe. Okay, thanks. I will have a look at RxJS methods, then.

Comment: the http request will be returned only once. why not use multiple streams of rsjs and the use concat method and return the results. i have not tried that but a simpler novoice way of doing it is- do a loop of all the requests and assign the results in an array and then when all of the iterations are done the return the final array of results

Comment: I watched videoes and read about rxjs after watching your comments. But I don't see how i could e.g implement the concatAll method. Is it possible for some of you guys to show me how its done with my example?

Comment: Try this. Just found this. The second link is interesting though I have not tried it myself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807725/angular-2-multiple-http-request-in-the-same-time https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: @Gary. Thanks, I will have a look at those and get back :-)

Comment: :-) In fact I also looked at it for sometime something I missed. Yeah I was trying out the loop logic of the novoice. Just forget that suggestion. I apologize. It will not work or wll be complex. It will need extra libs like asyncjs or somewhat similar and will be more complicated than rxjs. But frankly, after a second thought - why dont you change the REST API into one request that takes a req of array of bookids to get the response of prices of the books as single array. I believe the second one is easier and cleaner than doing multiple http req. What do you think?